# How can I track non-Steam game hours?

Tags: steam

Is it possible to track non-steam game hours? Almost any game was possible with Xfire when it was around, does Steam have a similar functionality?

If so, how do I do it?

Comment: I moved to Raptr after Xfire essentially became defunct.

Answer (score 7):

Steam does not offer any time tracking for non-Steam games.

It's a [greatly requested feature](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1731915), but there has been no word on reasoning or plans for the future.

That said, there are obviously various alternatives, such as the (now defunct) Xfire as you have mentioned. There appears to be no option that integrates directly with Steam.